# Showing 1 result with For Loop

Tags: c++

This is my code:

```
void IDsearch(vector<Weatherdata>temp)
{
    int userinput;
    cout << "Enter the ID of the Event and i will show you all other information: " << endl;
    cin >> userinput;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < temp.size();i++)
    {
        if(userinput == temp[i].eventID)
        {
            cout << "Location: " << temp[i].location << endl;
            cout << "Begin Date: " << temp[i].begindate << endl;
            cout << "Begin Time: " << temp[i].begintime << endl;
            cout << "Event Type: " << temp[i].type << endl;
            cout << "Death: " << temp[i].death << endl;
            cout << "Injury: " << temp[i].injury << endl;
            cout << "Property Damage: " << temp[i].damage << endl;
            cout << "Latitude: " << temp[i].beginlat << endl;
            cout << "Longitude: " << temp[i].beginlon << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

what im trying to do is to make it after looping through all of the value, if userinput doesnt match with any of those, then just print out "it doesnt match" once. I know if i use else or if(userinput != temp[i].eventID) it would just show "it doesnt match" multiple times. Im new to C++, please help. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can use a flag to remember if some elements are found.

```
void IDsearch(const vector<Weatherdata>&temp) // use reference for better performance
{
    int userinput;
    bool found = false;
    cout << "Enter the ID of the Event and i will show you all other information: " << endl;
    cin >> userinput;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < temp.size();i++)
    {
        if(userinput == temp[i].eventID)
        {
            cout << "Location: " << temp[i].location << endl;
            cout << "Begin Date: " << temp[i].begindate << endl;
            cout << "Begin Time: " << temp[i].begintime << endl;
            cout << "Event Type: " << temp[i].type << endl;
            cout << "Death: " << temp[i].death << endl;
            cout << "Injury: " << temp[i].injury << endl;
            cout << "Property Damage: " << temp[i].damage << endl;
            cout << "Latitude: " << temp[i].beginlat << endl;
            cout << "Longitude: " << temp[i].beginlon << endl;
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if(!found)
    {
        cout << "it doesnt match" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also `return` from the `if` instead of using a flag.

Comment: @Bob__ ... if it is guaranteed that no two elements in `temp` has the same `eventID`.

Answer (score 1):

a nice pattern, "old-days way" of doing it:

```
int i;
for (i=0; i<N; i++)
   if (...) {
     ...
     break; // i does not reach N
   }

if (i == N) { // never entered ifs in the for loop
```

still, use the flag as suggested in other answers! I tought it would do good to you to know this exists

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way of doing it, almost equivalent to using a break statement inside the for loop.

Just loop through the vector, and then print the result outside it.

```
unsigned int i = 0;
for(; i < temp.size() && userinput != temp[i].eventID; ++i);

if(i < temp.size() && userinput == temp[i].eventID)
{
    cout << "Location: " << temp[i].location << endl;
    cout << "Begin Date: " << temp[i].begindate << endl;
    ....
}
else
{
    cout << "it doesnt match" << endl;
}
```